# Characterization of non-negative Fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f(\omega) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} w_k \cos(k \omega)$ with $\omega \in [-\pi, \pi]$ be a finite and real Fourier series.

Is it possible to characterize for which coefficients $w_k \in \mathbb{R}$ this series is non-negative (i.e. $f(\omega) \geq 0$)?

Edit: Is is also possible to characterize for which coefficients $w_k \in \mathbb{R}$ this series is non-negative on the discrete domain $\{\omega_0, \cdots, \omega_{m-1}\} \subset [-\pi, \pi]$?

Comment: Do you mean $\cos(i \omega)$ vs $\cos(k \omega)$?

Comment: In a normal Fourier series $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, cos(n x)$ the condition $a_0>0$ is necessary but not sufficient. Your Fourier series is $2 \pi$-periodic. Are you really only interested in $\omega\in [0, \pi]$?

Comment: @StevenClark I think its possible to allow $\omega \in [-\pi, \pi]$. As $cos(-\omega) = cos(\omega)$ then $f(-\omega) = f(\omega)$ is its mirror around zero. (I also fixed the typo with $cos(k\omega)$ you pointed out)

Comment: I see now its sufficient to consider the interval $\omega \in [-\pi, \pi]$ since the function $f(\omega)$ is an even function of $\omega$.

Comment: the Feijer characterization can be useful $f \ge 0$ iff there is a polynomial (which can be taken to have no roots inside the unit disc) st $f(w)=|P(e^{iw})|^2$; this gives immediately conditions on the coefficients $\omega_k$ in terms of the coefficients of $P$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w_k=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ik x}\mu(dx)$ for some  positive measure $\mu$ if and only if $$\sum_{k,\ell}w_{k-\ell}\overline{c_k}c_{\ell}\geq 0$$ for all $(c_k)_{1}^n$ and all $n$. This is the Bochner theorem for the group $\mathbb{Z}.$ Have a look to Rudin, Real and complex analysis.

Edit. $f(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^nw_k e^{ikx}$ with $w_{-k}=\overline{w_k}$ implies that
$w_k=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ikx}f(x)dx$ and therefore if $f>0$ we have
$$\sum_{k,\ell}w_{k-\ell}\overline{c_k}c_{\ell}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)|\sum_{k=-n}^nc_ke^{ik x}|^2dx\geq 0$$ which is saying that the Hermitian matrix $(w_{k-\ell})$ is semi positive definite (this matrix is symmetric if you insist for taking $w_k$ real). The Bochner theorem says that conversely if the Hermitian matrix $(w_{k-\ell})$ is semi positive definite, then the trigonometric polynomial $f$ is positive. May be it is better to read the first chapter of Rudin Fourier Analysis on Groups, 1963.

Comment: Are you referring to Herglotz's theorem? Is this applicable when $w_i \in \mathbb{R}$?